# Why am I getting "It does not meet our quality standards" error?

Tags: support

When I submit my question, I get this error

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> It does not meet our quality standards.

I think it related to **accept rate** and if **accept rate** was higher it would be posted. What should I do ?

I know there is a similar question but I didn't get the answer

Comment: No it is not related to the accept rate, you should think more carefully about how you phrase your questions and use proper punctuation/capitalization

Comment: Note that `backticks` are typically used to indicate code fragments and commands, and not to highlight words.

Comment: @slhck ok, I will consider that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Here's why your questions are getting rejected. slhck had to edit 50% of your post to make it pleasant on our eyes.

**Make sure we don't have to edit your question and the system won't reject them**

Comment: I know, I'm doing my best :( . But what's the measure of `meet our quality standards` ?

Comment: There's no public measure. Try to use proper capitalization and punctuation. This will help in most cases. @hamed

Comment: Well you'll have to do more than your best. You can't seriously tell me you wouldn't be able to mimic slhck's edits on any of your future posts, its not rocket science you know

Comment: I will more carefull , thanks. @slhck